# java class declaring as public suggestion, intelliJ giving suggestion of converting into Abstract class

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

QuizActivity:-
This is my 2nd activity but its not working with appcompat v7 that I need for ActionBarActivity. And now getting error in bold  line of the code, help please
**public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity**  ,error in this line that "class "QuizActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract `getSuppourtFragment()` in CallBack "

MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2nd Activity:-

```
package quizapp.fyp.shanio.quizapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;



public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    }
}
```

Comment: "its not working" doesn't give us any details of the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Have you overrided all the abstract methods of ActionBarActivity

Comment: Why there are double stars? Are they formatting typo in SO?

Comment: **public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity**  error in this line that "class "QuizActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract 'getSuppourtFragment()' in CallBack "

Comment: @AmitK.Saha He was trying to bold the line.

Comment: Post your logcat to help you in right and better way.

Comment: is that all the code you have?

Comment: how do i get logcat? i cant run the project due to error in project

Comment: Post your Activity code if you can.

Comment: No it not, i basical have three classes but i dropdown the code to remove this error but still having this error

Comment: I posted the mainActivity,

Comment: please ensure you have actually build the project with this strip down code.

Comment: Builded but didn't worked and still not :(